# ListItem doesn't get highlighted when pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a ListView with a custom layout. I tried nearly everything I could find to make the items give a feedback when pressed (such as a button). I know that I should use a drawable-res with a selector as root element. I've tried to use this both as listSelector and as background for the single views, but it doesn't work. I also tried the drawSelectorOnTop without success.
So here are my layouts, maybe I did something wrong, but I just can figure out what it is.

MainActivity-Layout with the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.stegabach.magicalarm.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.stegabach.magicalarm.DigitalClockWithoutSeconds 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/next_alarm_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/add_alarm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_add_alarm"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_add_alarm"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:onClick="addAlarm"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:listSelector="#FFF"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no_alarms"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

The item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/item_selector">

<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/list_alarm_active_toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/list_alarm_time"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_alarm_active_toggle"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_alarm_days"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

And finally the selector for the drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/item_bg_normal"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_bg_pressed"/>
</selector>
```

Maybe I should mention that I use the same selector as background for some ViewGroups that should behave like buttons - thereit works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you set the necessary onItemClickListener listeners?

Comment: @MungaihKamau I do not use the ListViews onItemClickListener, for I need a clickListener for the item AND a clickListener for the togglebutton. I set both listeners in my adapter's getView().

Comment: Then thats why the listview row is not highlighted,because you havent set any click event listener to it.If you want it highlighted,deffinately you need to set a click listener to it.For now,it is the item and toggle button that should get highlighted when clicked respectively.Are they highlighted?

Comment: @mungaihkamau The togglebutton shows the usual behaviour when clicked. The whole item does not show anything, neither when the togglebutton is pressed, nor when any other position in the item is touched. The listener I set to the View (that is returned in my adapter's getView) itself works, but without any button-like feedback that it has been clicked (until another activity opens as specified in the onClick method).